# using spec2 from Play or from the normal distribution?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, specs2

I am working in a legacy project where the guys before me use the specs2 from play inserted through 
`libraryDependencies += specs2 % Test`
as well as the normal distribution 
`libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.8.5" % "test")` 
I am wandering which is better option, as I want to have just one distribution as don't see the need for both, what is the advantages of one over the other one, as well I want to have just one as the jars are conflicting for be debugged from IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Play! you are on, but looking at `2.5.8`, `specs2` from Play (`play.sbt.PlayImport.specs2`) [refers to the `play-specs2` library](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2ef49460d39f5eea7b715f36c04abd95fb7e7c32/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L54), which in turn depends on [specs2@3.8.5](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/34c24d808bb5d6672e7887ead578981fbfd5bb5e/framework/project/Dependencies.scala#L11-L16), but also adds some [Play! specific testing logic](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2ef49460d39f5eea7b715f36c04abd95fb7e7c32/framework/src/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test). Using `play.sbt.PlayImport.specs2` as a dependency, will allow your module to use both `specs2` and the `play-specs2` library.